# Custom back indicator image in iOS 7 not vertically centered

Tags: ipad, ios7, uinavigationbar

I am using the following code to use a custom image for the back indicator in my iOS 7 app:

```
UIImage *temp = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-black-on-black-normal-2"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorImage:temp];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackIndicatorTransitionMaskImage:temp];
```

The strange thing is, if I use an image that is 22px high (way too small for what we want, by the way), it centers vertically within in the nav bar just fine. Once I start to make it a more reasonable size, however, it gets way off vertically (here it's 44px high, still too small for us but not centering at all, as you can see):

[image]

Any help or suggestions greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25250389/ios-7-custom-back-indicator-image-position/45184644#45184644

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Check button image, is there any unwanted bottom space?

Comment: hard to see details, do you have bigger image?

Comment: @slxl sorry. i didn't get you.

Answer (score -1):

Try with the bellow code.

```
   UIImage *temp = [UIImage imageNamed:@"BackBarButton.png"];

   self.navigationController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:temp style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(back_Clicked:)];


 -(void)back_Clicked:(UIBarButtonItem*)loBtn
 {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: A little more explanation would be nice.

Comment: Don't do this, it breaks the left-to-right swipe gesture.